# Is possible to INSERT List instead of String?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to learn more with SQL and I am trying to INSERT a List of Numbers linked with 1 ID (row).

Now I figured out how to use List in SELECT, basics like

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE catalog_number IN ("CAT1", "CAT2", "CAT3");
```

and I am trying to do a similar thing but with INSERT

Something like this but this won't work, sadly.

```
INSERT INTO link_products ('main_product_id', 'linked_product_id') VALUES (124, IN(1,2,3,4,))
```

Basicly I am trying to do like php `foreach` command  fully in SQL (in `phpmyadmin`) and I am not even sure if this is possible.

The result should be (in database):

```
id | main_product_id | linked_product_id
1          124               1
2          124               2
3          124               3
4          124               4
```

Comment: You can insert multiple rows in one statement like this: `INSERT INTO tbl (col1, col2...) VALUES (1, 2, ...), (3, 4, ...), (5, 6, ...)`

Comment: PHP and sql are very different - sql does not have the concept of lists and it does have very strict rules about what is valid in a values clause (what you are attempting isn't) . mysql does have the concept of loops but only in stored programs(procedures,function,trigger,events) but not in select or insert or update or delete statements but such loops are in no way similar to php.

Comment: I see, thank you for explanation :) @P.Salmon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert the data like:

```
INSERT INTO link_products ('main_product_id', 'linked_product_id') 
VALUES (124, 1)
      ,(124, 2)
      ,(124, 3)
      ,(124, 4)
;
```

Comment: Oh I didn't even think of this chain of Values, thank you!

Comment: happens to me from time to time too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you'll need something like

```
INSERT INTO link_products ('main_product_id', 'linked_product_id')
SELECT 124, productId FROM  products WHERE catalog_number IN ("CAT1", "CAT2", "CAT3")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $servername="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $dbname="demon";
    //CREATE CONNECTION
    $conn=new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
    //CHECK CONNECTION
    if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {
        die("connection failed:".$conn->connect_error);
    }
    //$sql="INSERT INTO student(CATEGORY_NAME) VALUES ('PENDA')";
    //isset();
    //Die();
    if (isset($_POST["add"])) 
    {
        $sql="INSERT INTO category(CATEGORY_ID,CATEGORY_NAME) VALUES ('','".$_POST["CATEGORY_NAME"]."')";
        //echo $sql;
        //die();
        $result=$conn->query($sql);
        if ($result===TRUE) 
        {
            echo"NEW RECORD CREATED SUCCESSFULLY";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "ERROR:".$sql."<br>".$conn->error;
        }   
    }   
    $conn->close();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CATEGORY</title>
</head>
<body align="center">
<div>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <td align="center" bgcolor="lightblue"><b>CATEGORY:</b><input type="value" name="CATEGORY_name" WIDTH="1000" value=""/></td>
</br>
</br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```